# Rotating an image and moving it in proportion to its parents x and y

Tags: html, css, blazor, transform, webassembly

I'm trying to make an Image Preview component in Blazor using BlazorWheelZoom and then a custom rotate method, that can rotate the image 90 degrees in both directions.

I can easily make this work, by applying the following to the image element:

```
div.rotate90 img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

However when I then try to move the image after rotating it 90 degrees, it moves the image relative to itself.

Like this:

[image]

So seen from its own point of view it "THINKS" that it's moving upwards, but from my point of view it is not.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="rotate270 common" style="border: thin solid black; width: 510px; height: 510px; padding: 5px; background-color: lightgrey;" b-beatmol9sb="">
<!--!-->
<div class="alert-danger" b-beatmol9sb="">xxx</div>
<!--!-->
<img
    src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIiAvPg=="
    _bl_11=""
    style="background-image: url('/Img/apples.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 500px 500px; background-position: -89px -136px; cursor: default;"
/>
</div>
```

I just want the image to move the same way as the cursor. IT DOES, but only when I'm at 0 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parent `<div>` for the moving, and a child `<div>` for the rotating.

btw, you could consider inline `<style>` instead of a class if you want.  Then you could rotate any number of degrees you liked:

```
<button @onclick="()=>AdjustX(-10)"></button>
<button @onclick="()=>AdjustY(-10)"></button>
<button @onclick="()=>AdjustX(10)"></button>
<button @onclick="()=>AdjustY(10)"></button>
<button @onclick="DoRotate">Rotate</button>
@rotation.ToString()

<div class="movethis" style="position:relative; transform: translate(@(offsetX)px, @(offsetY)px)">
    <img src="/files/icons/Logo1.png"
         style="transform: rotate(@(rotation)deg) !important;">
</div>

@code {
    int rotation = 0;
    int offsetX = 0;
    int offsetY = 0;

    async Task DoRotate()
    {
        rotation = (rotation + 15) % 360;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    async Task AdjustX(int adjustment)
    {
        offsetX += adjustment;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    async Task AdjustY(int adjustment)
    {
        offsetY += adjustment;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Note that according to caniuse.com, the current browsers no longer need a prefix for "transform."

Answer (score 0):

Translate before you rotate.

```
transform: translate(@($"{translateX}%"), @($"{translateY}%")) rotate(@($"{angle}deg"));
```

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src='https://source.unsplash.com/daily' class="image-control" />
</div>

<input type="range" min="-90" max="90" @bind-value="@angle" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" @bind-value="@translateX" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" @bind-value="@translateY" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
@code {
    int angle = 0;
    int translateX = 0;
    int translateY = 0;
}

<style>
    .image-control {
        transform: translate(@($"{translateX}%"), @($"{translateY}%")) rotate(@($"{angle}deg"));
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .image-container {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

[BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/r1upm9yw)

Comment: What's this?  `style` tags on a Blazor component?  Since when has this been a thing?  Question: if you already have the .css defined somewhere else, is it additive, i.e. can you just add `transform` in your component?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I did this to present it all in one file. You can also just use it to define `:root` variables that the .css files can see.

Comment: Will it override already-defined variables?  Like, could I arbitrarily change the definition for a theme color, or possibly even animate it?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Want to see something cool copy paste this component into a wasm project. https://github.com/BrianLParker/ComponentViewer/blob/master/ComponentViewer/Views/Shared/BounceDemo.razor

Comment: That's pretty sexy.  I wish there was a way in Blazor server to force certain blocks or variables to function on client side only.  I'm about to re-purpose and old slide-show making app, and it would be nice to have smooth rotations and so on, but I don't think I can do that without JS due to latency.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Yeah thats why I said wasm. Wasm is even better at it now with AOT in .net6

Comment: I'm quite interested in WASM for my app now.  I made a question about how to integrate the two if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278163/integrating-blazor-server-side-with-wasm

Comment: Why do I have to move the image before rotating? What difference should that make? Now my image is just moved to another position, but when dragging it, it still goes the wrong way